# Customizing google custom search engine. Especially with changing the title font

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, google-custom-search

I have a custom google search engine on my website. The problem is that I am facing an issue where I just can't change the font of the search result titles. So when I try to resize my webpage the results looks too large and jumbled... I did managed to change the snippet size by:

```
.gs-snippet{
   font-size: 3vw;
}
```

However, when I tried to change the title like this

```
.gs-title {
         font-size: 3vw;
}
```

it just doesn't budge.... I do not know why it works with .gs-snippet but not with .gs-title. If you can figure out my issue of what I am doing wrong or if you can propose a different way to change the title then that would be great!

Thanks a bunch,
Archie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're overwriting a CSS style from Google, then !important is your answer. [Read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception). !important overrides other styles that don't contain !important.

```
.gs-title {
  font-size: 3vw !important;
}
```

Also, are you sure you want to use 'vw' as your unit for font size? I would suggest using either 'px' or 'em'. That may be the issue, or at least it's worth a shot.

Comment: THANKS! It worked :') I am using vw because I want the size of the font to change when a user changes the size of their window. Do you think it's a good idea? That was the reason why I did it...

Comment: Wait something weird occurred when I changed the title size... here is a screen shot: http://imgur.com/a/9Vo3p

Comment: notice how rest of the title sort sinks into the snippet

Comment: Huh, it's hard to tell from just a picture. My guess would be that that the word "abortion" has a class or ID on it that's affecting the font-size.